# "Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure" al usar ocrad.js

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de usar *ocrad.js* para obtener el texto de una imagen pero al tratar de obtenerlo dando click al botón sale *Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure.* y no corre la función ¿Qué puede estar saliendo mal?

```js
document.querySelector(".button").onclick = function() {

            var image = new Image();

            image.addEventListener("load", function() {

                var canv = document.querySelector(".image");

                var context = canv.getContext("2d");

                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

                var dat = context.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height);

                try {

                    var text_1 = OCRAD(dat);

                    document.querySelector(".result").innerText = text_1;

                } catch {

                    alert("Error");

                }

            });

            image.src = "Sin título.png";

        };
```

```html
<canvas class="image" style="width: 50%;border: 1px solid"></canvas>

    <br>
    <br>

    <textarea class="result"></textarea>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="button">Obtener texto</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en `context.getImageData()`. Prueba agregar esta línea luego de `var image = new Image()`:

```
image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```